# Shopify api versioning & cursor based pagination update

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Can anyone help me out how to add api_version & cursor based pagination in my current app. 
I am using shopify_app v(7.0.0) & rails v(4).
I have tried to add api-version while

`ShopifyApp.configure do |config|
config.api_version = "2020-01"
end`

but it throw an error `undefined method api_version=`.

Also i have one question that this  shopify_app 7.0.0 version is supports api versioning & pagination ?

Comment: Take a look at this issue on the ShopifyApp github: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/750

Comment: @scilence i have try same but still get error. I have added shopify_gem v(7.0.0). also i have one question in mind that this version is support API versioning ?

Comment: It appears they added the `api_version` configuration sometime between 8.6 and 9.0. You should really consider upgrading your entire stack, you're missing out on a _ton_ of bug fixes. They're up to version 13.3 of this gem, but they removed support for Rails 4 in 7.2.9. Changelog is here: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: And note. It takes way less time to just start a new Rails 6 project than try to bring a version 4 one up to 6. I would highly recommend you use latest Shopify App and Rails 6 from scratch and then paste in your old App code logic. Your App will simply stop working soon enough.

Comment: It same for the cursor based pagination ? Cursor based pagination support v(7.0.0)? or need i update shopify_app version ??